# Using @include inside a loop in SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create 24 grey lines, to show a blueprint of my grid.  Here is the image *(except pretend there are 24 grey lines)*.  Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tyuwb).

Is it possible to create a loop for `@include grid(1);` so it will repeat itself 24 times to mirror the image below?

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="hi" class="section">
    <div class="grid-lines">
    <div class="section-header">
        <h1>Grid</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
  #hi {
    width: 960px;
      @for $i from 0 through 24 {
      .grid-lines { 
        @include grid(1); }
      }
    background: #ccc;
    height: 500px;   
  }
```

Comment: As Nathan's answer states, you'd be overwriting css. However, you may be able to visually produce this with a repeating linear gradient background. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you @include a SASS mixin, you are basically just pasting in some CSS properties. In this case:

```
 display:inline;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 width: $columns*30px + ($columns - 1)*10px;
```

If you do this 24 times in your CSS file, you are just overwriting the same properties 24 times, not adding any more content (markup) to the page.

What you could do, is create your grid lines class once, and then use it 24 times in your markup:

SASS

```
.grid-line { 
  @include grid(1);
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
    <div class="grid-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I go about repeating the class `grid-lines` 24 times then?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Although this answer may have been helpful to OP. I am actually curious whether you can use `@include` inside an `@each` loop. Doesn't seem to work for me.